# Using a question mark when searching for a word to stand for any character

Tags: c++, string, dictionary

For a program I am trying to write, a .txt file is read in, then the number of words is counted (I used map). The program prompts the user for a word to find, and then shows how many times the word is in the file. I am supposed to have a part that includes a "?" to stand in place of a letter in a word, and print the number of times a word in the file could fit the description. The "?" could stand for another letter or a whitespace. I have no idea how to go about using this, and any help would be appreciated!

Example:
Please enter a word: a??
The word and appears 4 times in the document. The word as appears 1 time in the document. The word a appears 1 time in the document

The question mark character is entered in by the user, and can stand for any other character. The program is supposed to search the file and find and count any possibilities that would fit. For example, if the user entered a?d, the word "and" could be a possibility of what is counted.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2)
        cout << "invalid usage" ;
    //open file
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open(argv[1]);
    //variables
    map<string, unsigned int> wCount;
    int count = 0;
    int uCount = 0;
    //lowercase
    while (!infile.eof()) {
        string text;
        infile >> text;
        for (int i=0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            text[i] = tolower(text[i]);
        }

        //count words
        if (wCount.find(text) == wCount.end()) {
            wCount[text] = 1;
            count++;
            uCount++;
        }
        else {
            wCount[text]++;
            count++;
        }
    }
    cout << "The total number of word found in the file was " << count << endl;
    cout << "The number of unique words found was " << uCount << "." << endl;
    cout << "Enter the word you want to find: " << "";
    //find(infile, word);
    string in = "";
    getline(cin, in);
    while(in != "EOF") {
            cout << "The word " << in << " appears " << wCount[in] << " times in the file" << endl;
            cout << "Please enter a word: " << "";
            getline(cin, in);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your example is not clear. Could you post a more concrete example?

Comment: @ChrisD hopefully that helps!

Comment: I suppose you are going to have to take each word in your list and compare it against the input word one letter at a time. If the input letter is '?' then it doesn't mater what letter you are matching against, it gets a pass, otherwise the letters must be the same..

Comment: First I would write a single function to compare two strings taking the special `'?'` characters into account: `bool wildcard_compare(string wildcard, string word) { /*...*/}`. Return `true` if they match else return `false`. Then think about integrating that function into your current code.

Answer (score 0):

I like problems like these. They have applications in a ton of different domains of computer science; especially Bioinformatics. This should get you started. Following the advice given by Galik you can:

1) Strip the question mark characters from the string

```
std::string strip_wild_card(const std::string &pattern) {
    int q_index = pattern.find("?");
    return pattern.substr(0, q_index);
}
```

2) Find occurrences of pattern in text

```
bool wild_card_compare(const std::string &pattern, const std::string &text) {
    //implement this
    if(pattern is found in text)
        return true
    else
        return false
}
```

Hint: To check this we can use the [find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) function found in the STL. Hope this helps. Good luck!